# GitHub fork attempt says "No available destinations to fork this repository."

Tags: github

I forked a repo on GitHub. Now I want to also fork another user's fork of that repo, in order to contribute to that fork as well.

But I'm getting the message "No available destinations to fork this repository."

Is this because it's not allowed to fork both a repo and its fork? Why is that not allowed?

Comment: I get the same error message when I try to fork of a project that I have already forked. It is bit odd why I cannot have two forks since the 2nd fork has deviated so much of the first one.

Answer (score 3):

You can work locally in your own fork in your PC with forks of other people, you just need to add another remote.

You have the `origin` remote which is your GitHub fork, also probably you already added the original project as `upstream` (`git remote add upstream https://github.com/original_owner/project.git`).
If you want to work on someone else's fork you can:

- Add another remote: `git remote add someone_else https://github.com/someone_else/project.git`
- Download the changes of that someone else's fork: `git fetch someone_else`
- Verify that branch is already locally: `git branch --all`
- Change the position of `HEAD` to the new branch: `git checkout someone_else/master`
- Create a new branch for you based on the someone else's branch: `git checkout branch my_new_branch`
- With `git log --oneline` you can verify that changes are as expected.
- Do your thing, commit, push: `git push --set-upstream origin my_new_branch`
- Go to someone else's fork page on GitHub and the `Compare & pull request` button will be there so you can make that PR to that fork.

That's all, ideally all those changes will arrive to upstream but with dead projects you can still contribute to active forks.